# What does a restriction mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can anybody tell me what this notation means?

$A|_{ker A}=0$

or this:

$A|_{im A}=A|_{ker(I-A)}=I$

Generally, I basically don't know what this notation means generally?
Apparently a linear operator with such properties is diagonisable, but first I have to understand what this notation means.
The notes just mention it with no explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a function between sets $X \to Y$ and $Z \subseteq X$, then the restriction $f|Z$ is the function $Z \to Y$ given by $(f|Z)(z) = f(z)$.

Informally, a restriction keeps the rule but reduces the domain.

Note that this can have consequences. For instance, the restriction of $x \mapsto x^2$ to $(0,\infty)$ is injective but the original function with domain $\mathbb R$ is not.

In your linear algebra example, $A|(\ker A)=0$ means that $A$ sends every vector in $\ker A$ to the zero vector, which follows from the definition of $\ker A$. In other words, $A$ is the zero transformation in $\ker A$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I understand now. A restriction on the usable domain for the function. Great. Thanks @lhf

Comment: So that first one $A|_{ker A}$ is saying, in terms of matrix operation for instance, A(ker A) = 0. So it's basically saying A maps the kernel back into itself. Is that what it's saying?

Comment: Actually, no, sorry the kernel isn't 0. That was silly what I said. hmmm, let me think here.

Comment: Ok, just thinking too hard. Of course A|_{ker A} will only map to 0. Thanks for your help lhf and Fred.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ and $N$ non-empty sets and $f:M \to N$ a map.

If $A$ is a subset of $M$, then we can define the restriction$f_{|A} \to N$ of $f$ to $A$ by

$f_{|A}(a):=f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: Thanks @Fred, see my last comment above too.